# How to install openCV 3.1 with full cuda toolkit support?

Tags: opencv

I am installing openCV 3.1 following [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide) guide. However after running CMake I see the following output

```
NVIDIA CUDA
 Use CUFFT:                   YES
 Use CUBLAS:                  NO
 USE NVCUVID:                 NO
 NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 21 30 35
 NVIDIA PTX archs:            30
 Use fast math:               NO
```

I see that CUBLAS, NVCUVID and fastmath is set to NO. But I have installed cuda toolkit 7.5, so I don't understand why is it still NO, and how can I make so to install with full gpu support?
I am using Ubuntu 16.04, OpenCV 3.1

Answer (score 1):

The guide that you mentioned using does not appear to have a flag related to or set to turn on the fast math feature. As far as I am aware you need to specify this during the cuda toolkit build or it will not be included in the build.

For example if you are using NVCC you must use the --use_fast_math flag; as is indicated [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#abstract). So it is likely that the CMAKE scripting doesn't have that flag set anywhere either.